# Google Analytics - Custom Value for "dl" Parameter

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api, google-tag-manager

I'm using Google Analytics (gtag version) on my site, and am trying to prevent actual urls from being sent to Google Analytics. Specifically, I see the **`dl`** parameter contains the url:

[image]

**QUESTION:** How can I customize the value of the **`dl`** parameter?

My current setup is as follows (I'm testing locally, by the way). In the head, I've included the standard Google Analytics gtag code, with a few custom fields:

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=<TRACKING_ID>"></script>
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag() { dataLayer.push(arguments); }
    gtag('js', new Date());
    gtag('config', '<TRACKING_ID>', {
        'custom_map': {
            'metric1': 'time_to_interactive',
            'metric2': 'dom_content_loaded_in',
            'metric3': 'dom_completely_loaded',
            'dimension1': 'time_to_interactive',
            'dimension2': 'dom_content_loaded_in',
            'dimension3': 'dom_completely_loaded'
        }
    });
</script>
```

And then in a body load function, I have the following code:

```
window.gtag('event', 'load', {
    'event_category': 'CriticalRenderingPath',
    'event_label': document.title, //url,
    'time_to_interactive': millisToHumanFormat(interactive),
    'dom_content_loaded_in': millisToHumanFormat(dcl),
    'dom_completely_loaded': millisToHumanFormat(complete)
});
```

Google Analytics developer documentation is pretty inconsistent and terrible, and I was not able to find a clear answer there. On the old system (ga.js), [according to this](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#location), you can say:

```
ga('set', 'location', 'CUSTOM_VALUE_HERE');
```

But I have no idea how to do it using the new gtag version of Google Analytics. I've tried a similar thing - in fact I tried all of these:

```
gtag('set', {
  'pageview': 'TEST_PAGE',
  'dl': 'TEST_DL_PAGE',
  'location': 'TEST_LOCATION',
  'page': 'TEST_PAGE',
  'documentlocation': 'TEST_LOCATION',
  'documentLocation': 'TEST_LOCATION',
  'document-location': 'TEST_LOCATION',
  'document_location': 'TEST_LOCATION'
});
gtag('set', 'location', 'TEST_LOCATION');
gtag('set', 'pageview', 'TEST_LOCATION');
gtag('set', 'dl', 'TEST_LOCATION');
gtag('set', 'page', 'TEST_LOCATION');
gtag('set', 'documentlocation', 'TEST_LOCATION');
gtag('set', 'documentLocation', 'TEST_LOCATION');
gtag('set', 'document-location', 'TEST_LOCATION');
gtag('set', 'document_location', 'TEST_LOCATION');
```

Nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use page_location in your config as listed here, https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/pages

Comment: That was it! Thank you!